# Why is Phing running my build.xml, and then saying it doesn't exist?

Tags: php, maven, ant, phing

It's running my build.xml, when the error pops up that my build.xml is missing... This makes no sense.

```
<project name = "php_project" default = "build" >
    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Target: prepare -->
    <!-- ============================================ --> 
    <target name = "prepare" >
        <echo msg = "Making directory ./target" />
        <mkdir dir = "./target" />
    </target>
    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Target: build -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <target name = "build" depends = "prepare" >
        <echo msg = "Copying files to build directory..." />
        <echo msg = "Copying ./src/main/php/lib to ./target/lib directory..." />
        <copy file = "./src/main/php/lib" tofile = "./target/lib" />
        <echo msg = "Copying ./src/main/php/webapp to ./target/webapp directory..." />
        <copy file = "./src/main/php/webapp" tofile = "./target/webapp" />
    </target>
</project>
```

As you can tell, I'm using a PHP-Maven file structure, but PHP-Maven is dead so I'm switching to Phing. Composer is located in src/main/php/lib/vendor. My build.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
./phing build.xml
```

Output:

```
$ ./build.sh
Buildfile: ./build.xml
Override ignored for user property phing.file
Override ignored for user property phing.dir
Adding reference...
  +Task definition: ...
  +User datatype: ...
  +Target: prepare
  +Task: echo
  +Task: mkdir

BUILD FAILED
exception 'BuildException' with message 'Target 'build.xml' does not exist in this project.' in php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Project.php:935
Stack trace:
#0 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Project.php(867): Project->_tsort('build.xml', Array, Array, Array, Array)
#1 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Project.php(817): Project->_topoSort('build.xml', Array)
#2 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Project.php(797): Project->executeTarget('build.xml')
#3 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Phing.php(574): Project->executeTargets(Array)
#4 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Phing.php(172): Phing->runBuild()
#5 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/Phing.php(272): Phing::start(Array, NULL)
#6 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/bin/phing.php(43): Phing::fire(Array)
#7 php_project/src/main/php/lib/vendor/phing/phing/bin/phing(20): require_once('php_project/...')
#8 {main}

Total time: 0.0560 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ./phing build.xml

You are running phing with the target "build.xml". This target does not exist. But the build **file** phing uses as default exists, which is `build.xml`. If you want to run phing with a different build file name, you have to use the option `-f` or `--buildfile`, followed by the name of the file you want to use.

Because the existing target "build" is executed as default, you don't need to name ANY target at all.

`./phing` would do.

`./phing build` would also do, with explicitly naming the target to execute.

Comment: I think somewhere between installing Phing and trying to get archive_tar working, I lost the -f flag, because originally I pulled it [straight from the manual](http://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlpdf/manual.pdf), page 26, and put it in a build.sh file. Of course, I moved, edited, and deleted this build.sh file multiple times trying to get the archive_tar error fixed.